# POST working wierdly in yii2

Tags: post, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Below given is the code for my view

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            if($fanclub_count<2)
            {?>
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin();?>
            <?= $form->field($model_fanclub, 'crew_member_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(MovieCrewMembers::find()->all(),
            'id', 'name'),['prompt'=>'Select Crew','style'=>'width:50%']) ?>
            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Join'), 
            ['class' =>'btn btn-success']) ?>


            <?php ActiveForm::end(); 
            }?>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <?php
            if($user_clubs!=null)
            {
                foreach($user_clubs as $active_clubs )
                {
                    $image= '/movie_crew_members/' . $active_clubs[0]."_".$active_clubs[2];
                    $path = \Yii::$app->thumbler->resize($image,55,55,Thumbler::METHOD_NOT_BOXED,true);
                    ?>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="cache/<?php echo $path?>"></br>
                        <a href="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl( [ '/users/change_fanclub',
                        'id'=>$active_clubs[0],'userid'=>$user_id] ); ?>">
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-2x"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                echo "No Active Clubs";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

there are basically two things a dropdown box and a image with a icon which redirect to a action. Sometimes it works perfect sometimes not. ie,when i click the drop down it gets redirected to users/change_fanclub. how is it possible? dropdown is independent of action users/change_fanclub. then how come it get redirected there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using this

```
 <?php
                $form = ActiveForm::begin( [
                'method' => 'post',
                'action' => [ "users/profile","user_id"=>$user_id ],
                ] );

          ?>
```

i don't know why i got redirected to users/change_fanclub when i click on the submit button of model_fanclub instead of going to users/profile. But i removed the error by specifying the action in ActiveForm.